# The Minkowski Functional

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $K$, and let $U \subseteq V$. *The Minkowski functional* $p_U:V\rightarrow [0, \infty]$ is defined as follows:
$$
p_U(v) := \inf \{\delta \in (0,\infty) \mid: v \in \delta U\} 
$$
where $\delta U = \{\delta u :\mid u \in U\}$ (note that $p_U(v) \in [0,\infty]$).
Let $\varepsilon \in (0,\infty)$ and consider the following sets:
$$
\begin{aligned}
A & := \{p_U < \varepsilon\} = \{v \in V \mid: p_U(v) < \varepsilon\} \\
B & := \bigcup_{\delta \in (0,\varepsilon)}\delta U 
\end{aligned}
$$

Is it the case that $A = B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I will prove: (1) $A \subseteq B$, (2) $B \subseteq A$.

1. I will show that $A \subseteq B$. Let $v \in A$. Then $v \in V$ and $p_U(v) < \varepsilon$. We wish to show that $v \in B$, i.e. that there is some $\delta \in [0,\varepsilon)$, such that $v \in \delta U$. Indeed, since $p_U(v) = \inf \{\delta \in (0,\infty) \mid: v \in \delta U\} < \varepsilon$, there is some $\delta \in (0,\infty)$, such that  $v \in \delta U$ and $p_U(v) \leq \delta < \varepsilon$.
2. I will show that $B \subseteq A$. Let $v \in B$. Then $v \in \delta U$ for some $\delta \in [0,\varepsilon)$. We wish to show that $v \in A$, i.e. that $p_U(v) = \inf \{\mu \in (0,\infty) \mid: v \in \mu U\}< \varepsilon$, i.e. that there is some $\mu \in (0,\varepsilon)$, such that $v \in \mu U$. Just set $\mu := \delta$.

Q.E.D.

Note that $p_U(v) > 1$ implies $v \in U^c = V\setminus U$, and if $U$ is [balanced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_set), $p_U(v) < 1$ implies $v \in U$.